# The sum is throwing unexpected results

Tags: jquery

The below code is throwing sum as 11 instead of 2, any reason why?

2 textbox having id as cchangeshr and pchangeshr.

cchangeshr value = 1
pchangeshr value = 1
HrsRecord_1 value = 10.00

The query with regards Sum is SOLVED.... Thanks

```html
<script>
        var b;        
        var x = parseFloat($("#cchangeshr").val());
     var no1 = parseFloat($("#HrsRecord_1").val());
     var y =  parseFloat($("#pchangeshr").val());
     k =  parseFloat(x+y).toFixed(2);
     c = parseFloat(k / no1).toFixed(2);
     $("#tchangesper").val(parseFloat(c * 100).toFixed(2));
     var fin1 = $("#tchangesper").val();
        
</script>
```

Thanks,
Jigar

Comment: Because you're extracting x and y as strings "1" from the page, not integer 1s. You'll need to parse them before adding.

Comment: @Rup: Okies, lemme try quickly.. I will let u know shortly the output.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of doing `parseFloat(x+y)` you need to parse each of the two variables to a float, as `.val()` retrieves the text from the selector. So something like this should work:

```
    var no1 =  parseFloat($("#HrsRecord_1").val());
    var y   =  parseFloat($("#pchangeshr").val());
```

Comment: I did that only.. slight time differnce in posting.. ;) Thanks man